# Param value in controller is null

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I send a form in ajax but in my controller I don't have value, my value is null

I have a form (big form) and when i submit I call a metthod test()

```
    function test(rubricId) {
    
        var data = $('#r6_FormEditServiceParameters').serialize();

         $.ajax({
           url: $('#r6_FormEditServiceParameters').attr('data-ajax-url'),
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            processData: false,
            success: function (ret) {
            // Handle success
          }
        });
    }
```

and In my controller I don't have value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8Fbn.png)

My data is not null.

My model :

```
        public class ParameterRubricModel
        {
          public string RubricId { get; set; }

          public int ServiceId { get; set; }

           public IList<ServiceParameterModel> Parameters { get; set; }

           public IList<TreeViewItem> Childs { get; set; }

           public IList<string> ServiceToDuplicate { get; set; }
        }
```

And my data looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2PjP.png)

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: could you provide a minimal executed code for use to reproduce your issue, I don't find the error based on the current information.

Answer (score 0):

**First**: You have a typo error in the `processData` option. It should be spelled correctly as `processData`, not `proccessData`.

**Second**: When you are sending data using `AJAX`, you should also specify the content type of the data being sent. Since you are serializing a form, you should set the `contentType` option to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

**Third**: Ensure that your `ParameterRubicModel` in the controller has properties that match the names of the form fields you are serializing. The model binding process relies on matching form field names to model properties.

Updated Code:

```
function test(rubricId) {
    var data = $('#r6_FormEditServiceParameters').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: $('#r6_FormEditServiceParameters').attr('data-ajax-url'),
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        processData: false,
        success: function (ret) {
            // Handle success
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you I try but my value is null. My model match with the form. I have different tabs and on another tab I go through my method with my completed model. It's that on this form I have the null I imagine that maybe it's the form that is too large? I don't see what I could have done wrong

Comment: If the model matches the form and you are still getting a null value for your model in the `SaveParameterRubric` action, it's possible that the size of the form data being submitted is causing an issue. ASP.NET Core has a default limit for the size of form data to prevent excessive data submission, and if your form is very large, it might be exceeding this limit.

Comment: Open the `Startup.cs` file. Inside the `ConfigureServices` method, find the `services.AddMvc()` or `services.AddControllersWithViews()` line (depending on your application is configured).
`services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // For 10 MB
});`

Comment: thanks, I have in my configuration services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider() .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
 { options.SerializerSettings.MaxDepth = 2;options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;         options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = reserveReferencesHandling.None; }); services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
     options.Filters.Add(new HttpResponseExceptionFilter()));
I add services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => {
     options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
 });  but still nothing in my model